# Property 'item' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<Component<{}, any, any>>'.ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, apollo

"react": "^16.12.0",
"typescript": "^4.0.3",
"next": "^9.4.4"

So typescript is issuing the above mentioned error on the item prop `<Item item={item} key={item.id} urlReferer={urlReferer} />`, which is defined in the child component. How do I resolve this?

ItemListItems.tsx

[image]

Item.tsx

[image]

My partial repo: https://github.com/TheoMer/next_apollo

Comment: You are using the same name `Item` for an interface and for the component in both files, which can lead to typescript confusion.  It's also possible that your HOCs are not returning the appropriate type for their props.  But start by improving your naming.

Comment: Hey, @LindaPaiste Thanks for the heads-up regarding the naming convention, which I changed. Unfortunately, this did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved: Apollo HOCs require that InputProps are specified that mirror the props being consumed in the component:

component/Item.tsx

```
type InputProps = {
  item: Item;
  urlReferer: string;
};

type ChildProps = ChildDataProps<InputProps, Response, {}>

const userQuery = graphql<InputProps, Response, {}, ChildProps>(
  CURRENT_USER_QUERY,
  {
    options: { 
      fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
      pollInterval: 300
    },
  }
);

interface Props {
  data?: any;
  item?: Item;
  urlReferer?: string;
}

const ItemComp: FC<Props> = ({ item, urlReferer, data: { me, error, stopPolling, subscribeToMore }}) => {
```